# What Maven 3 archetype to use for Drools project on Jboss?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, drools

Objective is to set up developer environment for:
JBoss 7.1, Maven 3.04, Drools 5.3.0 , eclipse platform 3.72 (IDE for Java EE 1.4.2...)

Goal is to be able to follow tutorials and learn Drools using latest available versions of software - without running into version incompatibilities between different components.

Seem to be getting a lot of "missing reference" type errors in eclipse package explorer after compiling code examples in maven. I am a newbie so apologies in advance if this is an obvious question.

Examples appear to compile in maven fine, but when trying to integrate with Eclipse ide am having a lot of reference errors.  The version of Java SDK on my PC is 1.7.0_04.

Comment: What Maven plugin are you using for Eclipse? Switching to an archetype will just create a project outline for you--it won't magically resolve compilation issues inside Eclipse if the Maven project already compiles fine from the command line.

Comment: In Eclipse..Help..About..Installation Details : m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse v 1.0.200...    In Maven >>>maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli)

Comment: I suspect you'll still need to provide more details; if it works outside of Eclipse then it's an issue with Maven/Eclipse--not something likely helped by a new project using an archetype.

Comment: I was able to take non drools example and a clean installation of Eclipse and build java6 project in maven and it imported into Eclipse fine (only had to add the M2_HOME variable).  Thanks for your answer. It did help.

Comment: Also helpful was this series of tutorials on youtube... "Maven Tutorial 09 - Creating a Maven Project in Eclipse"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official maven archetype for Drools, and I doubt that any of the community ones are up to date.

Take a look at these resources:

- [Drools and jBPM version compatibility matrix](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/droolsjbpm-introduction-docs/html_single/index.html#compatibility)
- On [the download page](http://www.jboss.org/drools/downloads), section "Eclipse update site". IIRC, in 5.3 the plugin was part of JBoss Tools, but for 5.4 it's a separate update site as linked there.

Alternatively to using the 5.4 update site, you can download the droolsjbpm tools zip (5.4 or 5.3), unzip it and configure the plugin in eclipse as a local update site.

PS: I recommend upgrading everything to 5.4.0.Final, that's the latest and greatest community release.

Comment: Thank you. I will try these resources.